# Ionic Angular Capacitor Firebase: Google Login

Tags: ionic-framework, google-authentication, capacitor

Ionic Angular Capacitor Firebase app errors

using @codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth the suggested code is:

```
Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn();

async googleSignIn() {
  let googleUser = await Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn();
  const credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.authentication.idToken);
  return this.afAuth.auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);
}
```

Error msg: property 'auth' does not exist on type AngularFireAuth
I can get it to work with email signup but not with Google. thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

In the auth.service.ts:
Imports

```
    import { AngularFireAuth } from @angular/fire/auth';
    import '@codetrix-studio/capacitor-google-auth';
    import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
    import 'firebase/auth';
    import firebase from 'firebase/app';
```

GoogleSignIn:

```
    async googleSignIn() {
    const googleUser = await 
    Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn();
    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.authentication.idToken);
    return this.afAuth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential(credential);   
 }
```

Comment: You can also import 'auth' as follows:  import { auth } from 'firebase/app'; then you could use: the original code:    const credential = auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.authentication.idToken);

Comment: It works! Just change signInAndRetrieveDataWithCredential() to signInWithCredential() because first one is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import some libraries for it to be recognizable.Make sure you have installed all required firebase libraries for angular like angularfire and firebase.

I have this code working.

```
//first import AngularFireAuth

import {AngularFireAuth} from "@angular/fire/auth"

//then import firebase

import firebase from 'firebase/app';

//define auth variable of AngularFireAuth in constructor

constructor(private auth: AngularFireAuth) {}

async googleSignIn() {

 let googleUser = await Plugins.GoogleAuth.signIn();

  //use imported firebase to get user credential from google

  const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(googleUser.authentication.idToken);


  //Then use auth variable of AngularFireAuth to sign user using firebase authentication

  return this.auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

  //If you want to get user signed user details you can do this 

   return this.auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((userCredential: firebase.auth.UserCredential)=>{

   //userCredential object contains all details of the signed user.

   console.log(userCredential)
});


}
```